# How to deploy a Spring Boot Application and Mongodb on the cloud?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker-compose, cloud

How can i deploy an application consisting of Spring Boot Application and Mongodb on a server without leaking passwords ?

I built a spring boot application that has MongoDb as a datasource. I wrote a docker-compose file containing the configuration including the mongodb container username and password in plain text. My spring boot application image is on an external registry. I want to deploy the application on a DigitalOcean droplet. I thought about copying the docker-compose file into the server and running docker compose up but that will mean that the password is still in plain text. Any ideas or suggestions to avoid exposing the password?